Overlay PNG Images
I need to create a product with image overlay from AppSheet.
I immediately thought of calling an AppScript script listing the images in .png format and saving the overlay image. However, the image script is not directly supported, so I have to call the HTML.
The idea is this:
Below I have inserted a supposed composition of images. They are representative of a pair of pants, where there are models of the waist, the type of pocket and the background, the front of the pants:
knife pocket
waist_40
background
Assim tenho:
Codigo.gs
function testOverlayImages() {
  try {
    // Manually input your test file IDs and output folder ID
 
    var fileIds = ['12dNuA7z0HpwjjEWQqk_Ka11gRlZXg9gm',
'12aGTgwgQFS1FvBK-o1-H_lx7K_lIUVxF',
'1JYBKj80vA_sJ-yIHcww308G9FqIWmFqK',
'1HaDk5r1xIRqR3RwE-vCxrNDiUvuO3MNs',
'1IeEce1cygeexeS1CspISszPyKpvPtnce'
    ];
    
    var outputFolderId = "11mipFucwgcW0Vlei9dseMwVwglHtYJOe"; // Replace with your Google Drive folder ID where the result will be saved


  

    // Get the images by their file IDs
    var images = getImagesByIds(fileIds);

    // Create the HTML page for overlaying images
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Overlay');
    template.images = images;  // Pass images to the HTML template
    template.outputFolderId = outputFolderId;  // Pass the output folder ID to the HTML template
    var html = template.evaluate().getContent();
    
    // Return the HTML page to the client to process the overlay
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(html).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.HTML);

  } catch (error) {
    // Return error response if something goes wrong
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
      status: 'error',
      message: error.message
    })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}

// Function to get images by their file IDs
function getImagesByIds(fileIds) {
  var images = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < fileIds.length; i++) {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileIds[i]);
    if (file.getMimeType() == "image/png") {
      var imageBlob = file.getBlob();
      var base64Image = Utilities.base64Encode(imageBlob.getBytes());
      var dataUri = "data:image/png;base64," + base64Image;
      images.push(dataUri);
    }
  }

  return images;
}

// Save the overlaid image to Google Drive
function saveImage(base64Image, folderId) {
  Logger.log('Saving image to folder: ' + folderId); // Log the folder ID
  Logger.log('Base64 image: ' + base64Image.substring(0, 100)); // Log part of the Base64 string (first 100 characters)
  
  // Decode the base64 image
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(base64Image.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "")), 'image/png', 'overlay_image.png');
  
  // Get the folder by folderId
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  
  // If the folder doesn't exist, log an error
  if (!folder) {
    Logger.log('Folder not found!');
    return 'Folder not found!';
  }
  
  // Create the file in the folder
  var file = folder.createFile(blob);
  
  // Log the created file's URL
  Logger.log('File created: ' + file.getUrl());
  
  // Return the URL of the saved file
  return file.getUrl();

}
Overlay.html
  canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }



<h1>Overlaying Images</h1>


<script>
  // Images and the output folder ID passed from the server
  var images = <?= JSON.stringify(images) ?>;
  var outputFolderId = "<?= outputFolderId ?>";  // Get the output folder ID from the Apps Script

  function overlayImages() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    // Load the first image to set canvas dimensions
    var img1 = new Image();
    img1.src = images[0];

    img1.onload = function() {
      canvas.width = img1.width;
      canvas.height = img1.height;
      ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);  // Draw the first image

      // Overlay subsequent images
      for (let i = 1; i < images.length; i++) {
        let img = new Image();
        img.src = images[i];
        img.onload = function() {
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);  // Overlay the current image
        };
      }

      // After all images are drawn, convert to Base64 and send back to the server
      setTimeout(function() {
        var base64Image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        console.log('Generated Base64 image:', base64Image.substring(0, 100)); // Log the first 100 characters
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(url) {
          alert('Image saved! You can access it here: ' + url);
        }).saveImage(base64Image, outputFolderId);  // Use the outputFolderId when saving the image
      }, 10000);  // Allow time for all images to load and overlay
    };
  }

  // Start the overlay process
  overlayImages();
</script>

Below is an example of the overlay image. This image should be saved in a specific folder.
overlay_image
Can anyone help me where I'm going wrong?
I was hoping that by calling the function through the script I would be able to save the overlaid image. I inserted the images so that I can better understand the overlay, but I can't save them.
